# Ionic : 'App not installed' when there is an existing Ionic app on the device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, apk

why is that every time I am trying to install an Ionic app to a device which has an existing Ionic app (different app made with Ionic) in it, it says 'App not installed'. Is there any problem or needed to be modified in the config.xml? Or is there any other ways to solve this? Thank you in advance for the response.

Comment: Is it installing when you uninstall it and install ...?

Comment: Yes, when I uninstall the existing. The new one successfully installs.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of is that your application is not signed. Try to build a debug version and not release version of your application and then install it on your device. You can use 'ionic run' or copy/paste manually the output android-debug.apk file to your device.

Comment: Thank you sir, but how can I make my app signed?

Comment: Use this tutorial to build sign apk..                                                                                       
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-toturial-for-building-a-release-apk/15758